# How to read a CSV file line by line in Azure Logic App?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I have an Azure Logic app which picks a file from the Sharepoint site.
In the next step, I want to parse the file contents to read them line-by-line and to pass each line in an Azure function I have already created.

At this stage I am unable to fetch and loop through each line of the file. I can get the complete file only.

Any suggestion on how to achieve this?

Comment: It will be good to understand what operation are you trying to perform on each line?                                                                                                  As of now there is no out-of box connector or function in LogicApp which parses a CSV file line by line. You can always vote for new features 

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps?query=CSV 

You will have to pass the whole content to the Azure Function that you already have and perform the necessary operation on it..

Comment: please post this as an answer and I shall mark it. thank you.

Comment: @Nirman, how did you pass file from azure logic apps and get it in azure function. a example will be very helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of now there is no out-of box connector or function in LogicApp which parses a CSV file line by line. You can always vote for new features [feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps?query=CSV](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps?query=CSV)

1. You will have to pass the whole content to the Azure Function that you already have and perform the necessary operation on it

   Or
2. There is a CSVToJson connector available in LogicApps github repo to use

https://github.com/logicappsio/CSVtoJSON

*Not officially supported but should be able to use it.*

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there is a feature is Azure Logic App which can read Excel file from the given location.

Take a look at this blog - https://www.pmichaels.net/2018/04/22/what-can-you-do-with-a-logic-app-part-two-use-excel-to-manage-an-e-mail-notification-system/, it's written pretty well and should give you a heads-up about using the feature.

Comment: Thanks for Pratik with the updates. Yes, I agree this should be the solution going forward... unlike 2016 when we had limited options. Thanks :)